failed to get recent blockhash: Method not found at Connection.getRecentBlockhash on vanilla javascript mini app
so im trying to make a sort of a devnet sol lottery, and i keep getting that error. I'm using html and javascript with ajax and a cdn to carry this out, and im connecting the wallet seems fine but getting the block hashes has been impossible, i've tried EVERYTHING and its driving me insane please help here's the code:



    
    
    Get Recent Blockhash
    


    Connect to Phantom Wallet
    
<script>
    document.getElementById('connectButton').onclick = async () => {
        if (window.solana && window.solana.isPhantom) {
            try {
                const resp = await window.solana.connect();
                const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection('https://warmhearted-holy-valley.solana-devnet.quiknode.pro/104da1a35279230001f68b37a68bad846e2fb3ec');

                const public_key = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey(resp.publicKey);

                const { blockhash } = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = `Wallet: ${publicKey}\nRecent Blockhash: ${blockhash}`;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Connection error:", error);
                document.getElementById('result').innerText = 'Connection error. See console for details.';
            }
        } else {
            alert('Phantom wallet not found. Please install it.');
        }
    };
</script>

the cdn i'm using is https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@1.30.0/lib/index.iife.min.js
please help

That function is deprecated, see web3js docs and Solana RPC docs. It is removed in v2.0 and some RPCs are now running this version, so these deprecated methods are now often unavailable. You should use connection.getLatestBlockhash() instead.

i tried it even before posting the question, and then it says its not a "function" its not even recognized or maybe the problem is within the cdn, idk. it shouldnt be. Im going crazy

            const { blockhash } = await connection.getRecentBlockhash();

use getLatestBlockhash() here
read more about chnages https://www.helius.dev/blog/agave-2-0-transition

i've tried that, but then it says its not a function or something like that. It's confusing me tons

Oh that 1.30.0 version you're using is really old. Try using the latest 1.x version of @solana/web3.js. The equivalent file is probably https://unpkg.com/@solana/web3.js@1.95.4/lib/index.iife.min.js
